# How to print LU Decomposition?

Tags: java

I'm working on a little app on matrices and I'm using the class jama. I have a small problem in printing an LU Decomposition, I hope for your help. Here is the code of my app I miss the part of the display the LU Decomposition

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import Jama.*; 

public class autovalori {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    double[][] matrix;
int n;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Matrix size");
n = scanner.nextInt();

matrix = new double[n][n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){         

            System.out.printf("Value: " + i + " - " + j);
        System.out.printf("\n");
        matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();

    }
}

Matrix A = new Matrix(matrix);
EigenvalueDecomposition E = new EigenvalueDecomposition(A);
double[] d = E.getRealEigenvalues();

    System.out.println("Rango " + A.rank());

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    System.out.println("Eigenvalue " + d[i]);
}

LUDecomposition LU = new LUDecomposition(A);
Matrix L = LU.getL();
Matrix U = LU.getU();
int[] p = LU.getPivot();

}
}
```

Comment: basically you want to print a two dimensional array... `Matrix` may have a `tostring()` already doing that...

Comment: I would like to insert  Matrix L = LU.getL();  Matrix U = LU.getU(); in two simple two-dimensional array and print them using two nested for loops.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the `Jama` website and there are several `print` functions available, which are specified in the [documentation](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/).

Edit: Then use either

```
double[][] Matrix::getArray(); 
double[][] Matrix::getArrayCopy();
```

Comment: I would like to insert Matrix L = LU.getL(); Matrix U = LU.getU(); in two simple two-dimensional array and print them using two nested for loops.